# Why does Latex output a quadruple instead of a triple?

Tags: macros

To keep track of definitions in a paper, I've written two versions for some macros. One is just the macro, like `\mymacro` and the other is an unfolded version of the macro, which I usually call `\mymacro@unfold`. Then I've written a command `\unfold` such that if I write `\unfold{\mymacro}`, the output is `\mymacro@unfold`. That is at least how I intend it to work (and it does in most cases), but in this one it does not and I'm clueless about why.

The MWE is below. It first defines the `\unfold` macro and then defines two macros, `\cftalg` and `\extalg` with their unfolded versions. While the output of `\unfold{\cftalg{A}}` is `\cftalg@unfold{A}` as it should be, the output of `\unfold{\extalg{A}}` is `\cftalg@unfold{A}` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

%%%% To replace a token by another, use the following:
\newcommand{\@replace}[2]{#1}

%%%% Unfold replaces macros with their unfolded versions:
\newcommand{\unfold}[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar\cftalg{\@replace{\cftalg@unfold}}{%
  \@ifnextchar\extalg{\@replace{\extalg@unfold}}{%
  }}
  #1}

\newcommand{\algfont}{\mathbf}

\newcommand{\cftalg}{\algfont}

\newcommand{\cftalg@unfold}[1]{%
  ( \cftalgc{\cftalg{#1}},
    \cftalgf{\cftalg{#1}},
    \cftctxext{\cftalg{#1}},
    \cftempc{\cftalg{#1}})
  }

\newcommand{\extalg}{\algfont}

\newcommand{\extalg@unfold}[1]{%
  (\cftalgc{\algfont{#1}},
    \cftalgf{\algfont{#1}},
    \cftctxext{\algfont{#1}})
  }

%%%% The intended use of `\cftctx` is `\cftctx{\cftalg{#1}}`.
\newcommand{\cftalgc}[1]{%
  { \renewcommand{\cftalg}[1]{##1}
    #1
    }
  }

%%%% The intended use of `\cftfam` is `\cftfam{\cftalg{#1}}`.
\newcommand{\cftalgf}[1]{\mathcal{F}_{#1}}

\newcommand{\cftctxext}[1]{\epsilon^{#1}}

\newcommand{\cftempc}[1]{\phi^{#1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

We analyze some kind of algebras $\cftalg{A}$.
\begin{itemize}
\item Algebras of this kind are quadruples: $\unfold{\cftalg{A}}$
\item Underlying it is a simpler kind of algebras which is only a triple, but LaTeX thinks differently about this: 
      $\unfold{\extalg{A}}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: From a TeX point of view, `\cftalg` and `\extalg` are the same: both macros with replacement text `\algfont`. Do you perhaps want to compare the names of the macros themselves?

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes, that makes sense. So TeX immediately replaces both of them with their replacement text? I had thought it would wait a bit with doing that until the `\unfold` action was performed. So yes, I want to replace the token `\extalg` with `\extalg@unfold` when it is the first token in the argument of `\unfold`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparison in `\@ifnextchar` is based on `\ifx`. Because `\cftalg` and `\extalg` have the same definition, the branch with `\cftalg` is used even if the macro is `\extalg`.

A simple workaround is making the definitions of `\cftalg` and `\extalg` different, e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\extalg}{\@empty\algfont}
```

or

```
\newcommand*{\extalg}{\algfont}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

%%%% To replace a token by another, use the following:
\newcommand{\@replace}[2]{#1}

%%%% Unfold replaces macros with their unfolded versions:
\newcommand{\unfold}[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar\cftalg{\@replace{\cftalg@unfold}}{%
  \@ifnextchar\extalg{\@replace{\extalg@unfold}}{%
  }}
  #1}

\newcommand{\algfont}{\mathbf}

\newcommand{\cftalg}{\algfont}

\newcommand{\cftalg@unfold}[1]{%
  ( \cftalgc{\cftalg{#1}},
    \cftalgf{\cftalg{#1}},
    \cftctxext{\cftalg{#1}},
    \cftempc{\cftalg{#1}})
  }

\newcommand{\extalg}{\@empty\algfont}

\newcommand{\extalg@unfold}[1]{%
  (\cftalgc{\algfont{#1}},
    \cftalgf{\algfont{#1}},
    \cftctxext{\algfont{#1}})
  }

%%%% The intended use of `\cftctx` is `\cftctx{\cftalg{#1}}`.
\newcommand{\cftalgc}[1]{%
  { \renewcommand{\cftalg}[1]{##1}
    #1
    }
  }

%%%% The intended use of `\cftfam` is `\cftfam{\cftalg{#1}}`.
\newcommand{\cftalgf}[1]{\mathcal{F}_{#1}}

\newcommand{\cftctxext}[1]{\epsilon^{#1}}

\newcommand{\cftempc}[1]{\phi^{#1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

We analyze some kind of algebras $\cftalg{A}$.
\begin{itemize}
\item Algebras of this kind are quadruples: $\unfold{\cftalg{A}}$
\item Underlying it is a simpler kind of algebras which is only a triple:
      $\unfold{\extalg{A}}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Comparison based on the macro name

There are many ways to implement a comparison based on the macro name. The following implementation puts the first token `#1` into a macro `\unfold@param` and compares it to `\unfold@cftalg` and `\unfold@extalg`, which are macros that contain `\cftalg` or `\extalg` respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

%%%% To replace a token by another, use the following:
\newcommand{\@replace}[2]{#1}

%%%% Unfold replaces macros with their unfolded versions:
\newcommand{\unfold}[1]{%
  \unfold@#1%
}
\newcommand*{\unfold@}[1]{%
  \def\unfold@param{#1}%
  \ifx\unfold@param\unfold@cftalg
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  \cftalg@unfold
  {%
    \ifx\unfold@param\unfold@extalg
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    \extalg@unfold
    {#1}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\unfold@cftalg}{\cftalg}
\newcommand*{\unfold@extalg}{\extalg}

\newcommand{\algfont}{\mathbf}

\newcommand{\cftalg}{\algfont}

\newcommand{\cftalg@unfold}[1]{%
  ( \cftalgc{\cftalg{#1}},
    \cftalgf{\cftalg{#1}},
    \cftctxext{\cftalg{#1}},
    \cftempc{\cftalg{#1}})
  }

\newcommand{\extalg}{\algfont}

\newcommand{\extalg@unfold}[1]{%
  (\cftalgc{\algfont{#1}},
    \cftalgf{\algfont{#1}},
    \cftctxext{\algfont{#1}})
  }

%%%% The intended use of `\cftctx` is `\cftctx{\cftalg{#1}}`.
\newcommand{\cftalgc}[1]{%
  { \renewcommand{\cftalg}[1]{##1}
    #1
    }
  }

%%%% The intended use of `\cftfam` is `\cftfam{\cftalg{#1}}`.
\newcommand{\cftalgf}[1]{\mathcal{F}_{#1}}

\newcommand{\cftctxext}[1]{\epsilon^{#1}}

\newcommand{\cftempc}[1]{\phi^{#1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

We analyze some kind of algebras $\cftalg{A}$.
\begin{itemize}
\item Algebras of this kind are quadruples: $\unfold{\cftalg{A}}$
\item Underlying it is a simpler kind of algebras which is only a triple:
      $\unfold{\extalg{A}}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

A variant that scales better, if there are more than the two macros `\cftalg`, `\extalg`. The implementation assumes that `\<macro>@unfold` exists for each `\<macro>`. Such macro is declared as

```
\unfold@def\<macro>
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

%%%% To replace a token by another, use the following:
\newcommand{\@replace}[2]{#1}

%%%% Unfold replaces macros with their unfolded versions:
\newcommand{\unfold}[1]{%
  \unfold@#1%
}
\newcommand*{\unfold@}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{unfold@@\detokenize{#1}}{#1}{%
    \csname unfold@@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\unfold@def}[1]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname unfold@@\detokenize{#1}\expandafter\endcsname
  \expandafter{%
    \csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1@unfold\endcsname
  }%
}
\unfold@def\cftalg
\unfold@def\extalg

\newcommand{\algfont}{\mathbf}

\newcommand{\cftalg}{\algfont}

\newcommand{\cftalg@unfold}[1]{%
  ( \cftalgc{\cftalg{#1}},
    \cftalgf{\cftalg{#1}},
    \cftctxext{\cftalg{#1}},
    \cftempc{\cftalg{#1}})
  }

\newcommand{\extalg}{\algfont}

\newcommand{\extalg@unfold}[1]{%
  (\cftalgc{\algfont{#1}},
    \cftalgf{\algfont{#1}},
    \cftctxext{\algfont{#1}})
  }

%%%% The intended use of `\cftctx` is `\cftctx{\cftalg{#1}}`.
\newcommand{\cftalgc}[1]{%
  { \renewcommand{\cftalg}[1]{##1}
    #1
    }
  }

%%%% The intended use of `\cftfam` is `\cftfam{\cftalg{#1}}`.
\newcommand{\cftalgf}[1]{\mathcal{F}_{#1}}

\newcommand{\cftctxext}[1]{\epsilon^{#1}}

\newcommand{\cftempc}[1]{\phi^{#1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

We analyze some kind of algebras $\cftalg{A}$.
\begin{itemize}
\item Algebras of this kind are quadruples: $\unfold{\cftalg{A}}$
\item Underlying it is a simpler kind of algebras which is only a triple:
      $\unfold{\extalg{A}}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Do you think the second approach you propose is still practical when `\unfold` is used to unfold lots of macros (more than 20)?

Comment: @Egbert: I have added a version that scales better.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more simple approach to the given problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\folddef#1#2{\expandafter\def \csname unfold@#1\string#2\endcsname}
\def\unfold#1#2{\csname unfold@#1\string#2\endcsname}

\folddef3\cftalg#1{(\mathbf{#1},\mathcal{F}_\mathbf{#1},\epsilon^\mathbf{#1})}
\folddef4\cftalg#1{(#1,\mathcal{F}_\mathbf{#1},\epsilon^\mathbf{#1},\phi^\mathbf{#1})}

\def\cftalg#1{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

We analyze some kind of algebras $\cftalg{A}$.
\begin{itemize}
\item Algebras of this kind are quadruples: $\unfold4\cftalg{A}$
\item Underlying it is a simpler kind of algebras which is only a triple:
      $\unfold3\cftalg{A}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```